# How do I include time also instead of just the date when adding new data to a table - PHP

Tags: php, html

Can you please help me find out how I can add the time of also instead of just the date when adding new data to a table.

The code is in PHP.
I have the following code but it does not show or add the time as you can see from the attached screen shot (figure1) when inserting new data to the table.

```
<?php
    $created = $row['created'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? $row['created']: null;
    $created_on = ! empty( $created ) ? ' On ' . $created : null;
?>
```

Would very much appreciate if you could please let me know what I am missing?

### Code to add new transaction

```php
public function add_new_transaction( $cusotmer, $amount, $type, $date, $expired, $other ){

    // Init Session
    if ( ! isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
        session_start();
    }

    if ( !empty( $cusotmer ) && !empty( $amount ) && !empty( $date ) && !empty( $type ) && !empty( $expired ) ) {
        
        $add_tansaction = $this->db->prepare( "INSERT INTO transactions ( id, customer_id, transaction_type, amount, added_by, transaction_date, expired, paid, other, created ) VALUES ( '', :customer_id, :transaction_type, :amount, :added_by, :transaction_date, :expired, 'no', :other, CURDATE() )" );

        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':other', $other );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':amount', $amount );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':expired', $expired );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':customer_id', $cusotmer );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':transaction_type', $type );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':transaction_date', $date );
        $add_tansaction->bindparam( ':added_by', $_SESSION['current_user']['username'] );

        if ( $add_tansaction->execute() ) {
            $this->display_msg( 'success' , 'The transaction has been added!.' );
        } else  {
            $this->display_msg( 'error' , 'Due to an unknow error. The Operation was not successful.' );
        }

    } else  $this->display_msg( 'error', 'You have entered an incorrect value/s.' );

}
```

### Output

```html
<td class="uk-row-infos">
   <i description="Added By <?php echo $row['added_by'] . $created_on; ?>" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
   <i description="<?php echo $this->get_edited_by( $row['edited_by'] );?>" class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                            
   <i description="<?php echo $this->get_transaction_expiration_date( $row['expired'], $row['paid'] ); ?>"class="fa fa-hourglass-end"></i>
</td>
```

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RKmy.jpg)

[figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7eQ.jpg)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmeXn.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vCfM.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your code? What does these variables do? Do they post data to database or retrieve from it

Comment: First thing is to change your database column to a DATETIME instead of just DATE type

Comment: Rifky, they post to a database and then retreive.

Comment: @BrokenArrow Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed this but it now only shows 0000 - refer to figure2 I attached to the question.

Comment: How do I make it show actual time and also change data format to UK please? I very much appreciate the quick responses on this - thank you!

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to help you: the code you show is just outputting whatever has been retrieved from the database, it isn't formatting it in any way. The code you need to find is either where it is being inserted into the database (you can't format a time if it isn't stored anywhere) or where it is being formatted as it is retrieved from the database.

Comment: @IMSoP I have added the insert command above. Is that enough info?

Comment: You shouldn't do this in code. Define the created field in your database as having a default value of the current date and time with time zone information so that you can be flexible enough to present that data as needed using native data formats.

Comment: @Volker247 Next thing is to check where you are inserting the DATE, change the code to insert both the DATE & TIME to that column. Finally, you should successfully be able to get the full DATE TIME values. Warning: Your data & time values might be affected by the MySQL time zone.

Comment: @BrokenArrow Thanks! The date and time now show but I don't know where to change the time zone so left with incorrect time. Should be set to London time zone.

Comment: If were you, would have used PHP "ini_set("date.timezone", "GMT")" to set application time zone first, immediately when the application starts, and would have issued the SQL "SET time_zone = 'GMT'" to set MySQL session time zone too to keep both the application & database aligned to same time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your code but i can help you in a way
Try these:
In php first add these code:

```
$time = date("h:i:s a");
```

This code will get the time (The time will be according to UTC)

then add the $time to the variable in which you stored the date that you printed there code is below:
I let that `$beforedatestored` is the variable in which you stored the date

```
$beforedatestored = $beforedatestored.$time;
```

Put these codes
It shall work
If you are having problem send the code i shall help

Comment: everything is working fine expect the date and I don't want to make too many changes as this code was developed by someone else but he's no longer in the country and I have lost contact with him as he has created the website for me but I wanted to add the time now instead of just date.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you need to change is when the data is being inserted into the database. Re-formatted for readability, you have this SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO transactions
( 
    id, customer_id, transaction_type, amount, added_by,
    transaction_date, expired, paid, other, created
)
VALUES
(
    '', :customer_id, :transaction_type, :amount, :added_by,
    :transaction_date, :expired, 'no', :other, CURDATE() 
)
```

Note that the value being inserted for `created` is `CURDATE()`, which is a built-in MySQL function. If you look up [the MySQL documentation for `CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) you will see this description:

> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric context.

So, the time is not being recorded.

If you look elsewhere on that documentation page, you will see there is [a different function called `NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) which includes both a date and a time:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' or YYYYMMDDhhmmss format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric context.

So you want to use that in your insert statement instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO transactions
( 
    id, customer_id, transaction_type, amount, added_by,
    transaction_date, expired, paid, other, created
)
VALUES
(
    '', :customer_id, :transaction_type, :amount, :added_by,
    :transaction_date, :expired, 'no', :other, NOW() 
)
```

This will store the full date and time for new rows from then on. To format the result however you like, you can then use [the `DATE_FORMAT` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when you retrieve (`SELECT`) it. There are plenty of details and examples in the manual.

Comment: Thanks so much @IMSop! worked beautifully. The only left now is to change format to UK and also use UK time please?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the result after applying the changes you suggested. I just need to change date format to DD/MM/YYYY and UK time please which is now 13:55

Comment: @Volker247 I've added a link to the appropriate part of the manual that tells you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @IMSop but I don't have select for retrieving data. Not sure under which section I'm meant to add

Comment: @Volker247 Well, it's coming out of the database somewhere, and you're in a much better position to find out where than someone who doesn't even have the application to look at. If you just want to get it done without learning how the code works, I suggest finding someone with some programming experience who'll help you out in return for a small fee, or a friend who you can trade favours with.